# Why Moderator will decide what is displayed in community forum?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I have just recently added a comment on a question that was something related to the problem I was facing. And then someone (so-called moderator) flagged the question saying it is like a commentary or question over a question. And it was hidden.
Though he was kind of right in saying that question was a question. But I have a problem here.
Moderators have full control over what will be displayed here in the community. And I am not getting any chance to explain anything. Which I think should not be the case in open community forums like this. Instead of moderators, they seem like a dictator.
So I will explain a reason here why I have added a comment over a comment.

Recently WordPress Gutenberg has released something which is still in kind of beta version and not lot of people have tried it. I tried searching for questions or comment related to the problem but could not find. And finally, I found a question that was something related to my problem. And even in that question, answer was given by the same person who has raised the question. It clearly shows that it's hard to get an answer, as not a lot of people have tried this thing.
That is the reason instead of asking a new question in the forum I raised a question inside question as he might be having the first-hand answer to the question.

Would like to hear some words from the moderator. Or maybe they can block this question too. And I am not new to these community forums it's just I have recently switched to WordPress.

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure as to the specific post you are talking about, but from what I can discern, it sounds as though you created an Answer post to express your own issues related to a question, as you do not have enough reputation to post an actual comment - is this correct?

Comment: I agree with bosco: post as a new question. But there's also the [Gutenberg issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues) you can use to report an issue, and the [support forum on wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/gutenberg/). (I'd also hope that whoever flagged or deleted your answer left you a friendly and useful comment when they did - apologies if not.)

Comment: @bosco Yes that was the reason i couldn't add this as a comment.

Comment: @Rup Github tracker is there to track issues related to Gutenberg. What I am facing is not an issue. And I don't think with all the problems we faced ourself should be created in a tracker. It is not a good practice either. And even if it is then probably we should close this platform all together and lets  everyone go to tracker site.

Comment: @JMT OK, I didn't see your question so I don't know specifically what your problem was, and whether it was an issue or not. if it's not a bug in Gutenberg then don't ask about it there, no.

Answer (score 6):

**Stack Exchange sites are not forums**, either in format nor content. The Q&A format is a model which all Stack Exchange sites adhere to, and the tools and interfaces which Stack Exchange provides rely on posts practicing that format in order to best facilitate the structure of help and knowledge sharing which is it's goal.

I'm not certain, but the comment and flag you describe sounds like one I might have made in the last week (I'm not a moderator - but was it me? :O).

There [are a handful](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) of [actual moderators](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) who have the tools and responsibility to act on exceptional circumstances, but it's worth noting that all Stack sites' content is community-moderated. Any community member with a reputation high enough for the corresponding [privileges](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) can play a role in the moderation process, which largely consists of voting to close and reopen questions, editing to improve and categorize content, and reviewing first posts and suggested edits. [Flagging posts is a privilege](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) unlocked for all users with 15 reputation.

All of these procedures are all guided by the network and the site's rules and guidelines. Discussion regarding those rules and guidelines is certainly encouraged, which is largely [why these meta sites exist](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). There are usually moderators hanging out in [our main chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) as well.

It sounds to me like you might have posted a question or critique of a question or answer as an Answer, in which case the moderator's action was less dictatorial and more just enforcing a rule that stands (to the best of my knowledge) across all of Stack Exchange's 175+ sites. There was no judgement on the value of the content you posted - it was simply posted incorrectly per the network's rules.

The [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help)'s ["Why and how are some answers deleted?" page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) succinctly details,

> Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question

As your very first post on the site, it was so quickly noticed and addressed for ending up in [the "First Posts" review queue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-posts), where reviewers are given specific guidance to ensure answers actually answer the question, and to flag them in the case which they do not.

If you do have a question which you would like help with, by all means post it as a new question! Dropping a link in there to the Question you were originally posting on for additional context is totally a good move as well. I for one would loooove to see a lot more Gutenberg hubbub on this stack.

If you did not have a Question but were only commenting on another post there, that would be something which would be better left in an actual comment on the post. Until you have accrued 50 reputation to unlock the privilege you are only able to comment on your own posts, however.

Comment: Yes, it was you only who have marked my comment. Anyway. the concern I raised was not about you specifically but I had concern in general. I am quite active in java section but completely new to this WordPress area. And the problem I faced today can be faced by anyone(New Member). I am new to the Site. I don't have enough reputation to comment. And then suddenly someone blocked my answer which I was looking for eagirly. And this might be really frustrating for a developer.

Comment: In that perspective I believe a chance should be given to the concerned person to respond and if the legitimate reason given by the person let the answer stay there. 

Coz irrespective of what you call it (forum or QnA), the sole purpose of the site is to help each other. And if we can not help each other in the name of rules then I think we are losing the essence of the site. 

Hope you understand.

Comment: You're welcome to go back to your answer and flag it for moderator intervention if you think it should be undeleted - there should be a 'Flag' link at the bottom. Flag the question if you can't find your answer. And that will go to the actual elected moderators not us. However it does sound to me like you should just ask it as a new question instead.

Comment: And brand new members do get a message by the answer box asking them to "avoid asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers". Since you've been active in the Java section before I guess it didn't show you that.

Comment: It does seem unfortunate that the commenting threshold is as high as it is. But perhaps things would be worse if it were lower. I consider both my flag and the comment I left as actions conducted in the name of "helping others" - again, your question has a much better chance of being answered if you post it as an actual question. The flagging and deletion of your Answer is something that would likely occur on any other stack; it sounds like you take less issue with this site and more with the format and rules of Stack Exchange as a whole.

Comment: Which, to be clear, I'm not saying these sites cannot be off-putting to newcomers. But I don't think it's something we can really do much about(?). I try to be kind in my comments to first-posters, but I understand and agree with the rationale behind the rules as they relate to the network's format - Answers which do not answer the question should be deleted, as is detailed in the [help].

Comment: RE: `"In that perspective I believe a chance should be given to the concerned person to respond and if the legitimate reason given by the person let the answer stay there"` - please understand that your Answer was deleted because it clearly violated the network's rules, not our site's. StackOverflow (where you have a few posts) has [exactly the same rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). If you would like to pursue the issue further, you should push for reform of the network's procedures on [the Stack Exchange Meta Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @bosco. Yes you were kind. You were never rude and that's why I said this is not about you but the process itself. As for as the rules are concerned these are made to facilitate the process and I am never of the opinion to remove the rules. But on the other side as you are saying. probably there should be some way to convert the answer which more looks like a comment ( true in my case) can be converted to a comment by a moderator like you.  I don't think I will follow up on the network procedure enhancement but if in any way this thread can help in that direction then it will be good. Regards

Comment: Again, I am not a moderator. I ran for moderator once in my ignorant youth, seven years ago, and I was not remotely close to being elected. I think I got like 1-3 votes total . I did get a neat t-shirt though. I am just a community member striving to help enforce the rules as they are - and the guideline here is far above me, as well as our site's commendable moderators. I am sorry for becoming defensive. You do make a good point - I would like to see it all more welcoming, somehow, as you describe. I am sure even my nicer comments drive people from the site.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Answers should answer the question. Yours didn't attempt to answer the question, and was not an answer so someone flagged it for moderator intervention. It should have been left as a comment instead.

As Bosco said, this isn't a discussion forum, and questions are not discussion threads. Users post questions, then other users try to write an answer that definitively solves the question. Comments can be left by users to clarify the question, and a minimum reputation is needed to prevent spambots flooding the site with comments for mystery pharmaceuticals.

I found the deleted answer, and it looks like you did not write the solution to the question. It is instead, a comment containing a new question. It should have been posted as a comment.

Posting it as a solution can signal to the site and other users that solutions have been written for the question, which wasn't the case ( it was actually a question ), so these get flagged for cleanup by other users. In this case it was flagged by a non-moderator for moderator attention.

Users need a minimum amount of reputation to post, which isn't specific to this stack. If you have 100 reputation on any stack, you get 100 reputation one very other stack you join. I would recommend you do this on a stack of your choosing, if only to gain the perk that removes the adverts.

Comment: I know I didn't write the answer to the given question and the reason is already explained in the above section (Read). And here I am not contesting that I have written an answer but the issue any newcomer might face. And what exactly do you mean by saying "I would recommend you do this on a stack of your choosing, if only to gain the perk that removes the adverts."

Comment: as you gain reputation you get perks, e.g. high ranking users have limited moderator powers. One of those things that gets unlocked is removal of the advertisements. Also having 100 rep on this stack means you instantly get 100 rep on every other stack, meaning you can comment everywhere on the network without having to build the initial reputation. It makes life so much easier. Other things include seeing the breakdown of up and down votes on questions and answers, etc

Comment: But also, again, this is not a discussion forum, and questions are not discussion threads. This is a seperate, independent answer, it is not a reply to Bosco, or a continuation of a thread of discussion. The reason my answer appears after Boscos is because Boscos answer has more upvotes and the default sorting is by votes. There is no _"above"_. If you switch the toggle to active then my answer is now first and Boscos is below. Answers should be self contained too